# Retrieve all italic text snipets on a page in jQuery and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom-traversal

I'm looking to run a script on a page that puts each piece of text that is italicized into an array.

As I understand jQuery `.find()` you can't get items by attributes, am I right?

Comment: Can we see some of your html?

Comment: do we have to write all the code?

Comment: Sketching out an app that runs client side, gathers up italiziced/bolded text while you read a page and kicks up a document overlay with a voter app for each 'bullet'. Found some very cool and mobile friendly ways to do this with roating image and html5 arcs. You could then direct the user to create a comment and add opinions to the text field. Kinda like rating attributes on a product. No server side yet. Researching the required tech, no code yet. If anyone wants to help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You should get familiar with the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method which is a great jQuery feature. You can define a filter function you can use to reduce the elements in your jQuery collection to the ones that fit your needs.
- You also need to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) which is another super-handy method that can help you create lists from your jQuery collections defined by a function you write. Using `.get()` you can create a plain Javascript array from this jQuery list object.

This is a basic version that will collect you the text content of elements that have `font-style: italic` applied to them:

```
var arr = 
    $('*') /*look at all elements*/
        .filter(function () { /*filter these elements*/
            return $(this).css('font-style') == 'italic'; /*only keep the italic*/
        })
        .map(function () { /*create a new object using these elements*/
            return $(this).text(); /*store the text of each selected element*/
        })
        .get(); /*convert this to an array*/
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nd8ew/1)

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. This will help a lot.